# For the following function, determine whether it is a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the following a homomorphism? Justify your answer.

$$φ : G \to \mathbb{R}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & 0\\b&a\end{pmatrix}\to b/a$$

Here $\mathbb{R}$ is a group under addition, and $G=\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right):a,b\in\mathbb{R},a\ne0\right\}$ is a group under multiplication.

Comment: the left side should read: a 0 on the top and b a on the bottom line. The right side of the arrow should read b/a. The text got moved when I posted the question.

Comment: Let me know if I interpreted your post correctly, in terms of formatting.

Comment: You need to define $G$ and $R$ for us. If you already have some thoughts on the problem, it would be good to hear them as well.

Comment: Yes the interpreation is correct. G is the Group G = (a 0 b a)
:a, b ∈ R, a does not equal 0.

Comment: (R, +) is the other Group with R meaning real numbers.

Comment: What is the group operation on $G$? Matrix multiplication? or matrix addition?

Comment: Matrix multiplication

Comment: OK - now you should check the definition of homomorphism. Take matrices $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}c&0\\d&c\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, and multiply them together. If $\varphi$ takes the result to $\frac{b}{a}+\frac{d}{c}$, then you do have a homomorphism. I hope this last statement is clear, please ask if not!

Comment: I am very confused about what φ actually is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A, B \in G$,   $$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\b & a\end{pmatrix},\quad a\neq 0, \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} c & 0\\ d & c\end{pmatrix},\quad  c\neq 0$$

By definition of $\phi: G\to \mathbb R$, $\quad \phi(A) = b/a,\quad \phi(B) = d/c$.

Now, you need to determine whether the following is true:

$$\phi(AB) = \phi(A) + \phi(B)$$

---

**ADDED**

$$AB = \begin{pmatrix} ac & 0\\bc+ad& ac\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\phi(AB) = \dfrac{bc + ad}{ac}$$

$$\phi(AB) = \dfrac{bc + ad}{ac} = \dfrac{bc}{ac} + \dfrac{ad}{ac} = \dfrac ba + \dfrac dc =\phi(A) +\phi(B)$$

What does this tell you?

Comment: I understand that I need to determine if it is true but I get confused when I try to determine φA and φB. I am stuck on showing how to determine it.

Comment: By definition of $\phi$, (as you've defined $\phi$, and as I've indicated in my post): $\phi(A) = b/a, \;\phi(B) = d/c$: The lower left entry divided by the upper left entry. To determine $\phi(AB)$, you need to first *multiply* (compute $ A\cdot B$), and then determine $\phi(A\cdot B)$. Again, you can do this by dividing the lower left entry of AB by the upper left entry of AB.

Comment: Oh ok. So I got AB = ac and o on the top and bc+ad and ac on the bottom. Does that seem right?

Comment: and φAB = b/a + d/c

Comment: Yes, indeed it does. I've gone ahead and supplemented the post. Let me know if it's clear.

Comment: Yes ist clear now :D thank you so much for your help! Sorry for taking so Long!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry about time, Vicky. Learning and mastery always take time!